# Downloading the .ai (adobe illustrator) file - file seems to be corrupt

Tags: php, http-headers

I have this code:

```
            $bmpblob = file_get_contents($image);
            header('Content-type: application/postscript');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$id1.'.ai"');
            echo $bmpblob;
```

But when I download this file it's corrupted.

I have similar code for .psd files and it's working:

```
            $bmpblob = file_get_contents($image);
            header('Content-type: image/psd');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$id1.'.psd"');
            echo $bmpblob;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I found out, what was causing corrupted image, so consider it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was the matter.

When I opened the file I download in Notepad++, I noticed, that in the end of the file I have:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: im in <b>/home/rukia/gallery/application   /controllers/IndexController.php</b> 
on line <b>279</b><br /><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagedestroy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource 
in      <b>/home/rukia/gallery/application/controllers/IndexController.php</b>
 on line    <b>279</b><br />
```

So thus file was corrupted.

It strange, though, that .psd files had the same on the end and they worked perfectly :)